# Get values from JSON with if statement where one of the data is just show '[]'

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I've get stuck and need any help to solve this problem. I want to get data from 'units.number' and 'units.type'. But in my JSON data, there are units that have a value of '[]'. Thanks before.

This is my JSON data :

```
{
    "data": {
        "shipment_summary": {
            "destinations": [
                ...
                {
                    "orders": [
                        {
                            "id": "31818",
                            "number": "84092202",
                            "units": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "31819",
                            "number": "803839747",
                            "units": [
                                {
                                    "number": "510812021",
                                    "type": "BUNDLE"
                                },
                                {
                                    "number": "510812040",
                                    "type": "CARTON"
                                },
                                {
                                    "number": "510812041",
                                    "type": "CARTON"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want get the data like this :

Order 1:

This orders doesn't have any units.

Order 2:

510812021 - BUNDLE

510812040 - CARTON

510812041 - CARTON

Comment: You have to check first units array has value or not like if (orderobj[index].units.length > 0) { ....then you can access inner data otherwise not. Because units array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = [{
                "shipment_summary": {
                    "destinations": [

                        {
                            "orders": [
                        {
                            "id": "31818",
                            "number": "84092202",
                            "units": []
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "31819",
                            "number": "803839747",
                            "units": [
                {
                    "number": "510812021",
                    "type": "BUNDLE"
                },
                {
                    "number": "510812040",
                    "type": "CARTON"
                },
                {
                    "number": "510812041",
                    "type": "CARTON"
                }
                            ]
                        }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }]


            var data1 = data[0].shipment_summary.destinations[0].orders;

            for (var i = 0; data1.length > i; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; data1[i].units.length > j; j++) {
                    console.log(data1[i].units[j].number + '-' + data1[i].units[j].type);
                }
            }
```